# Android update multiple local SQLIte tables, from remote MySQL server(PHP), what should I do?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-asynctask

I need this for a custom app, built for a specific company, so it will not be on Google Play.
I have an app, that uses about 15 SQLite tables. It needs to be able to work offline and online, so I have to use SQLite to keep information for the offline part.
The main idea is that when user on Android touches a button, an update process is starting.
The logic of the update is:

1. For each local table I have a AsyncTask class dealing with the update process described bellow
2. Every local SQLite table have an "_id" field (autoincrement) AND "idremote" field to be filled with MySQL id of the record (plus the rest of the fields)
3. Each time the update starts, the app prepares a string containing all "idremote" id's from the local table and sends it to the server
4. On the server side, a PHP file receives the string of ID's and checks in the MySQL table, to see if there are new ID's that are not in the received String of ids (each AsyncTask has it's own php file on the server)
5. If the PHP finds in MySQL table new ids, then it sends the new records using JSON back to Android
6. I process the resulting JSON in onPostExecute of the AsyncTask and insert the new records in the SQLite table

So I have 15 AsyncTask classes that all perform the same operations as above, each of them dealing with a specific table.
I also do the update of the remote tables sending the new records to MySQL through the same mechanism

My problem is that I want to be able to see/know when the update is done/finished so I can notify the user of that fact, but since we are talking about multiple AsyncTasks ... that run simultaneously... I have no idea how to implement this. How to find out when all the AsyncTasks are done?

Or is there a better way to do this task? The update of the local/remote tables?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be using a `SyncAdapter` which is designed to handle syncing changes to a remote server in the background.

You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

You should ignore the section "Creating a Stub Content Provider" and create a content provider to access your existing SQLite database.

Comment: I know about this syncAdapter, but my serverside is PHP+MySQL so I did not find any example on how to do that using my specifications

Comment: It doesn't matter what your server architecture is, you need to implement the API request code into the `SyncAdapter`

Comment: But, "You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application. " so why should I create a content provider?

Comment: Could you point me to a working example of using the SyncAdapter combined with php-server side? Or can you give me some code directly on how to update at least one single table (SQLIte <--> MySQL) ?

Comment: In order to work with SQLIte I use a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Is there no example of how to use these together? I mean the SyncAdapter and the SQLiteOpenHelper ?!!??!?

Comment: "You don't need a provider to use an SQLite database if the use is entirely within your own application." - I don't know why they still keep this in the docs, there are many advantages to having a content provider, it doesn't even make sense not to if you are using a `SyncAdapter`. Also if you search the Google developers YouTube channel you'll find a Google IO talk from 2010 explaining exactly why you should use a content provider.